# Understanding equal power crossfades

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, algorithms

I'm trying to implement an equal power crossfade between two uncorrelated signals ($A$ and $B$). From what I understand I need to setup the crossfade in the following way

Come up with a function $f(x)$ that determines the gain applied to a signal where $x$ is from $0$ to $1$. And $0$ represents being all the way faded to signal $A$,and $1$ represents all the way faded to signal $B$.

$f(x)$ should satisfy:
\begin{cases}\begin{align}
f(x)^2 + f(1-x)^2 &= 1\\
f(1) &= 1\\
f(0) &= 0
\end{align}\end{cases}

- So I could use the [square root cross-fade](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/q9bd0e0drf) $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$:

  [image: square root cross fade]
- Or I could use the [$\cos$ cross-fade](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xxvud7li3d) $f(x) = \cos\left(\frac{π}{2}x\right)$:

  [image: cos cross fade]

My question is where does this $f(x)^2 + f(1-x)^2 = 1$ restriction come from? I know that we interpret sound pressure on a logarithmic scale but I don't understand why a quadratic relationship is required between two signals to maintain equal perceived volume.

Comment: it's because when signals are perfectly correlated, an equal-voltage crossfade $$ f(x) + f(1-x) = 1 $$ is what you are looking for.  but when there is **zero** correlation (not a negative correlation), the equal-power crossfade $$f^2(x) + f^2(1-x) = 1$$ is what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equal power crossfade](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14754/equal-power-crossfade)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was aware of that post before posting this questions and it is the reason I asked this questions. It does not explain why x^(1/2) should be used for uncorrelated signals

Comment: Ah! Now we have a new, even more precise question! Please edit your question, unaccept my answer.

Comment: @rob amended my answer. Could you comment on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power of a (real-valued) digital signal $s[n]$ is simply the $s[n]^2$ (or proportional to that, depending if you want to normalize or not).

That's why the constant sum power constraint **is** $f^2(x) + f^2(1-x) = 1$. That's simply the definition of constant sum of  powers, nothing more.

---

so, what you've *not* specified is "logarithmic scale" to **what**, or what the perceived quantity is.

And the answer is perceived *volume* is logarithmic to *power*. The fact that this relation is logarithmic doesn't really matter here – it's only important that to achieve the *same* perceived volume, you need to have the *same* power.

Your functions $f$ work on *amplitude*, and thus, the square comes from the amplitude-to-power relation, not from the power-to-perceived-volume relation.

---

Ok, this question has become kind of a moving target. I'll try to explain what's up here, in the order my process of thought allows *me* to explain it:

1. Perceived volume is a function of signal energy. That is, to get the same perceived volume, you need to produce the same energy.
2. Power of a signal is proportional to the square of its amplitude, so with $s(t)$ being our signal, $s^2(t) =  \text{const.}$ restraint is very intuitive; energy of that  signal within $\tau$ time units is $\int_{T_0}^{T_0+\tau}s^2(t)\,dt$.
3. Your signal processing happens on amplitudes; you add amplitudes, not powers. Thus, let $s(t) = a(t) + b(t)$. It follows directly that $s^2(t) = a^2(t) + 2a(t)b(t) + b^2(t)$. Notice the middle $ab$ term!
4. But the formula we have dictates that $a^2(t) + b^2(t) = 1$. This only makes sense if $\int_{T_0}^{T_0+\tau} 2a(t)b(t)\,dt\equiv 0\quad\forall T_0, \tau$. Which is exactly the case if $a$ and $b$ are uncorrelated. If $a$ and $b$ were correlated, the $ab$ crosscorrelation term could not be equal to 0.

Comment: But equal power cross fades are defined for a reason. They don't have an audible dip in volume when fading between two signals. Why is that?

Comment: Because the perceived volume is roughly proportional to power. The reason for that is physics / anatomy / psychoacoustics. (also, your original question was "I don't understand why a quadratic relationship is required between two signals to maintain equal power."; the question you're asking in this comment is "why does constant power mean constant perceived volume", and that's a different one and should probably asked separately instead of in a comment :) )

Comment: that's what I'm trying to understand. I thought the ear responded to pressure on a logarithmic scale so it is confusing to me that power would be proportional to perceived volume as it is not logarithmic. I would have though that the perceived volume of two combined signals would be their sum in dBs

Comment: My questions is "where does this f(x)2+f(1−x)2=1 restriction come from". And it comes from the relationship between perceived volume and power

Comment: I edited the last word in my question to make it more clear

Comment: see my edit, @rob.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I thought that what was I explained – logarithm isn't what is relevant to the problem, it's the fact that you need to provide constant power (and I must admit that I simply assumed the two signals to be orthogonal without explaining that; I'd much rather see this question marked answered with your answer than mine accepted.). I hence marked the question as duplicate and plan to delete my answer later today (it doesn't add anything)

Comment: we have to explain that adding uncorrelated signals adds power and adding correlated signals adds voltage so the power has an extra cross-product term.  we have to show why and then show how that translates to crossfade functions.  this *music-dsp* post i did tries to generalize the concept and Olli wrote up something that had similar results.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson tried to salvage things. I hope it fits rob's actual question; I kind of feel he revised what he's actually asking.

Comment: Marcus, i finally got around to copying my *music-dsp* answer to this Stack Exchange.  but this answer is for the other [equal-power crossfade question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14754/equal-power-crossfade/49989#49989) that appeared earlier.